# Default selected text when editing a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, text, focus, edit

Basically, I'm trying to set the behavior of my Edit Mode to select the containing text upon entering the edit mode. I'm trying to edit a property `Name` of a `TreeView.Item`.

My research showed that I should use something like `TextBlock.Focus()` and `TextBlock.SelectAll()`, but I don't see how I could do that, as I'm using this approach for my edit mode:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72544/Editable-Text-Block-in-WPF?msg=5098686#xx5098686xx

Any ideas?

Comment: Showing us the code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add The SelectAll() as shown here:

```
public EditableTextBlockAdorner(EditableTextBlock adornedElement)
    : base(adornedElement)
{
    _collection = new VisualCollection(this);
    _textBox = new TextBox();
    _textBlock = adornedElement;
    Binding binding = new Binding("Text") {Source = adornedElement};
    _textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    _textBox.SelectAll();
    _textBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
    _textBox.MaxLength = adornedElement.MaxLength;
    _textBox.KeyUp += _textBox_KeyUp;
    _collection.Add(_textBox);
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, simple and efficient. Sorry about missing that!